# URL rewrite guide

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

my url is like below :

```
http://localhost/project/test/jobs/?page=accounting

<a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>jobs/?page=accounting">Accounting</a>
```

And i want to make like below :

```
http://localhost/project/test/jobs/accounting
```

i have search other question but unable to make it. As i am totally unaware about this .htaccess rewrite process :(

however i have below code already in my htaccess file to remove .php extension :

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

please help me to append URL rewrite rule in above htaccess file without loosing .php ext rule.

Answer (score 0):

you are making get request with params which remains as it is if u wana make post request then it will be somethong like this
http://localhost/project/test/jobs/accounting

Comment: OP wants htaccess rule bro.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do with link building is sending all my traffic to my index.php whitch splits it into a MVC framework, this is the important **part of my .htaccess for you**:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*) index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**What does this .htaccess do rule by rule?**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

http://www.maxi-pedia.com/FollowSymLinks

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Checks or the requested file isn't a direct path to a directory or actual file, correct me if I am wrong, because I am not 100% sure.

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Rewrites the path from "/test/testings/lalalala" into "index.php?path=/test/testings/lalalala".

I hope that this was the answer where you were looking for.